# Bootstrap carousel is filling my whole page

Tags: html, css

I would like a carousel that fills about half of the window.  I've been reading through the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/ and a following a youtube tutorial for help https://youtu.be/9cKsq14Kfsw?t=3510.  My images fill the entire page plus more (when scrolled down) and I can't figure out how to make it smaller other than setting a fixed height in CSS which makes the image look squashed.

Here is my code

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Image carousel -->
    <div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Carousel images -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="img/home-1.png" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1 class="display-2">Garnet Home Inspections</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/home-2.png" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Service Area</h1>
                    <h3>I travel all over the capital Region</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">SET UP AN APPOINTMENT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/home-3.png" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <!-- put content here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Carousel buttons-->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>   <!-- Screenreaders only -->
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>   <!-- Screenreaders only -->
        </a>

    </div>
```

Thank you in advance :)

If anyone needs more information/code please let me know.

Comment: Is the carousel being instantiated? Why are you forcing size on the images?

Comment: @isherwood I'm not forcing the size of the image, is that the only way to do it?  In the video tutorial I was watching he didn't so I assumed that bootstrap would automatically fit the carousel to my screen without being too large.  Maybe I missed something though.  If I were to force the size of the image would I just crop them?

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing your entire page. Maybe you can replicate the issue in a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0vw43oaj/

Comment: @isherwood https://jsfiddle.net/0vw43oaj/1/ I would like the image to be much much smaller vertically without squashing the image if that makes sense.  So for example at fullscreen, this image would take up about 1/2 of the page.

Comment: @isherwood for instance, with a small screen width my image looks like this https://i.imgur.com/vypza3x.jpg and a large width my image looks like this https://i.imgur.com/P95e9XY.jpg